# How microservice apps are better than cluster of monolithic apps cluster with load balancing

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

How micro-service apps are better than cluster of monolithic apps cluster with a load balancer ?

I already know that micro services are :-

1- easy to develop 
2- helps for continuous delivery

in what other ways it's better ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of availability, if a monolithic application breaks in production due to one little thing that effects all clustered nodes, all functionality associated with it goes down.  This could be an critical business function that can literally prevent an organization from operating, resulting in loss of income.

On the other hand, if that "little thing" happens to break every instance of an event-driven microservice with asynchronous endpoints, it can go down and affect only one aspect of functionality which is temporarily unavailable.  The rest continues happily running along.  When the faulty service is fixed, it "catches up" with its processing and everything runs normally again.

Now take this with a grain of salt. Depending on your business case and the criticality of the specific microservice that goes down, the above advantage might not be realized. But the architecture certainly stacks more odds in your favor in that regard.